# Ajax - mvc request always fails

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I would like to hit an action in a controller from a view, have it return a result.  However I always get a "request failed", then the action code in the controller executes.  I am trying to use this in the view:

```
$("#State").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != "Va") {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ProcessOrder","Checkout")',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(result) {
                    if(result.success) {
                        alert("good " + result);    
                    } else {
                        alert("bad " + result);
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("request failed");
                }
            });

        } else {
            formSwitcher($(this).val());
        }

    });
```

And this in the controller:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ProcessOrder()
    {
         string sURL = @"https://someUrl/?OrderId=" + Id ;
         var badUrl = string.Empty;
            try
           {
               Response.Redirect(sURL, true);
               HttpWebRequest request = null;
               HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = null;
               request = HttpWebRequest.Create(sURL) as HttpWebRequest;
               request.Method = "GET"; // Supports POST too
               httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
               return Json(new { success = true });
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
                badUrl = "~/Shared/error.aspx";
           }
           return Json(new { success = false, error = badUrl });
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Firstly, never return or redirect from within a try catch. Redirecting will result in an error.

Comment: is ajax call going to controller?

Comment: Yes - the alert for request failed shows then the controller code runs

Comment: learn firebug/chrome web tools, will help you a lot with ajax development

Comment: What omu means by this is to open up Google Chrome and click F12.  Then go to network and initiate your AJAX request.  It will appear as failed, click on it and look at the response.  The response will contain your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was Response.Redirect(sURL, true); was throwing an exception which was caught by ajax before it was caught in the try catch.  The result was that the ajax said there was a failure, the code continued to run.